# Using multiple content service from .net client?

Tags: content-delivery, web8, sdl-tridion, web8.5, microservices

Is there a way, based on some condition can I connect to different content services? e.g.: I have two different discover services and based some scenario I would need to fetch data from an another discovery/content service. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible: yes.  Just don't use the supported client libraries, you could talk directly to the web services.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. As Nuno mentions in his comment, you may opt not to use the CIL library in your web application and use a Web Service Reference to directly connect to the OData Content Delivery service. This means that you can rig up your own logic to determine when and where to make the connection.

Tridion's (SDL Web's) OData implementation follows the OData protocol documented by Microsoft (e.g. here: http://www.odata.org/documentation/). So you can leverage it however you need in your implementation.

Comment: Just keep in mind all that the client SDK does - caching, ADF, OAuth, etc

Comment: Remembering that this is a _partial implementation_ of the OData protocol (per http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-2F41CB23-912F-4149-9C16-34AB00E67E4E)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. CIL can connect to only one discovery/content service per instance.

Comment: Thank you vinayk. I was wondering if there is an option to override SDL content library and override the endpoint url

Comment: I don't think it is possible at CIL level, as the content client is designed to work with only one Content service at any point of time.